# Can I run a class on Notification Click?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have a activity named as MainActivity.java which contains the Custom Notification Builder. Here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button bcustomnotify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.customnotification);
bcustomnotify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            CustomNotification();
        }
    });
}

public void CustomNotification() {
    // Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.customnotification);

    // Set Notification Title
    String strtitle = getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle);
    // Set Notification Text
    String strtext = getString(R.string.customnotificationtext);

    // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
    // Send data to NotificationView Class
    intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);
    intent.putExtra("text", strtext);
    // Open NotificationView.java Activity
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            // Set Icon
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            // Set Ticker Message
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.customnotificationticker))
            // Dismiss Notification
            .setOngoing(true)
            // Set PendingIntent into Notification
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            // Set RemoteViews into Notification
            .setContent(remoteViews);

    // Locate and set the Image into customnotificationtext.xml ImageViews
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotileft, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotiright, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    // Locate and set the Text into customnotificationtext.xml TextViews
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle));
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, getString(R.string.customnotificationtext));

    // Create Notification Manager
    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Build Notification with Notification Manager
    notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

}
}
```

and I have a class in another activity named as anotherActivity.java which goes like this :

```
public class anotherActivity extends Activity {
// some code
}
```

Now the **Question is**

***Is it possible to run the class of another activity after the notification of MainActivity is clicked without actually opening the another activity as pending intent?***

Comment: `AnotherActivity` should be what you are using for your `PendingIntent`, then.

Comment: @CommonsWare No, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to run the class of another activity after the notification of MainActivity is clicked without actually opening the another activity as pending intent?

No.

If you want tapping on a `Notification` to do something with no visible UI, do not use `getActivity()` on `PendingIntent`. Use `getService()` or `getBroadcast()` and route to an appropriate component.

If you are saying that you want a tap on the `Notification` to show one activity (apparently named `NotificationView`) *and also* do something from `AnotherActivity`, then `AnotherActivity` should be merged into `NotificationView`, or the common code refactored into another class, or something. Your `PendingIntent` can do *one thing*: start an activity, start a service, or send a broadcast.

Comment: If I use getService() or getBroadcast() will I be able to perform initializations in it? like we use TextView textView;

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal: I have no idea what "initialization of declarations" means.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal the answer given answers your question, it also gives you more details. If you haven't asked the right question you should edit your original question - not simply ask more questions in comments.

Comment: @CommonsWare I really appreciate your answer and +1 for that too :)

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal: Subclasses of `Service` and subclasses of `BroadcastReceiver` can have fields, just like subclasses of `Activity` do. You would not have a `TextView` in a `Service` or a `BroadcastReceiver` as (usually) they do not have a UI. And a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` only lives for one call to its `onReceive()` method, so it would not need fields. Services and receivers are covered in the docs and just about any book on Android that you choose to read.